# LINQ query to match values in inner collection

Tags: linq

Looking for a LINQ implementation to handle following use case.

Pesudo definitions of object:

```
class Product{
int Id;
string Name;
IList<ProductAttribute> ProductAttributes;
}

class ProductAttribute{
int Id;
string Name;
string Value;
}
```

I have collection of products that look something like:

```
[
{"Name":"Red Large Shirt", "ProductAttributes": [{"Name": "Color", Value:"Red"},{"Name":"Size", "Value":"Large"}, {"Name":"Type", "Value":"Shirt"}]},
{"Name":"Red Small Shirt", "ProductAttributes": [{"Name": "Color", Value:"Red"},{"Name":"Size", "Value":"Small"}, {"Name":"Type", "Value":"Shirt"}]},
{"Name":"Red Large Pant", "ProductAttributes": [{"Name": "Color", Value:"Red"},{"Name":"Size", "Value":"Large"}, {"Name":"Type", "Value":"Pant"}]},
{"Name":"Blue Large Shirt", "ProductAttributes": [{"Name": "Color", Value:"Blue"},{"Name":"Size", "Value":"Large"}, {"Name:"Type", "Value":"Shirt"}]},
]
```

I need a LINQ statement that returns list of products that match certain attributes.
E.g. Return list of product where ProductAttribute ("Name"="Size" && "Value"="Large") && ("Name"="Color" && "Value" = "Red")

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be too easy to use the best answer without having tried (and thus learned) anything before.

Comment: Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq) for a basic starting point into LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.Any()` or `.Contains()` extension. For example,

`products.Where(p=>p.ProductAttributes.Any(a=>a...condition here for attributes))`

Comment: Your comment provided starting point and I managed to build on top of it.